# Set icons using ionic.js and CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

How can i set own icons in tab using CSS? Now i'm using icon-on="icon ion-ios7-clock" for default, but i want to use my own.

```
<ion-tab title="Фильтр" icon-on="icon ion-ios7-clock" icon-off="icon ion-ios7-clock-outline"
             on-select="places.onFilterTabPress()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your own icon css class like it's done with all the ionic icons for example the `ion-ios7-clock` you're using. It's actually a font with icons which is used there.

If you have a font which you want to use as your own icons then you could just copy the class found in the ionic.css:

```
.my-custom-icon:before {
      content: "MyIconFontContent";
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: "MyIconFont";
      speak: none;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      text-rendering: auto;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

if you want to use an image you could use it as a background-image in your defined class instead of the font stuff. but you probably have to set a fixed width and height.

Comment: i have done like you has said.                                           `.my-custom-icon:before {
 display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  speak: none;
  
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-image: url(icons/assets/01._main_iPhone_assets/icon_2.png);
}`                                             but image doesn't appear